# data-bind text with dash in property name

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How do I access a property in a binding with an invalid variable name.  For example:

```
// {"customer-name": "Explosion Pills"}
<span data-bind="text: customer-name">
```

This will try to subtract `name` from `customer`.

The following does not work:

```
<span data-bind="text: 'customer-name'">
```

as it will literally print out "customer-name."  How can I access this property in a binding?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following format:

```
<span data-bind="text: $data['customer-name']"></span>
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kqntA/

Answer (score 2):

This works :

```
<span data-bind="text: $data['customer-name']">
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5LgWR/)